# Table border Is popping out on lower right hand

Tags: border

I am working on a table and for some reason, when I added `rowspan`, the border is popping out a little bit on the right side.

[image]

Is there a way I can merge the border?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, why don t you share the html code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3">
                    <tr class="top_box" style="background-color:#001F5B;">
                        <td>Loan<br />Amount</td>
                        <td>Term</td>      
                        <td>Monthly<br />Payment</td>
                        <td>Rate</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr class="big_box">
                        <td style="background-color:#C7DDF3;">$1,000</td>
                        <td class="blue_1">24 months</td>      
                        <td class="blue_2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>$45.68<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="blue_3">8.99% APR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="big_box">
                        <td style="background-color:#C7DDF3;">$5,000</td>
                        <td class="blue_1">36 months<br/>48 months<br/>60 months</td>      
                        <td class="blue_2">$158.98<br/>$124.40<br/>$103.77</td>
                        <td rowspan="3" border-collapse="collapse" class="blue_3">Includes 0.75% <br/>promotional <br/>rate discount<br/> and 0.25% <br/>rate discount<br/> for auto debit</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="big_box">
                        <td style="background-color:#C7DDF3;">$15,000</td>
                        <td class="blue_1">6 months<br/>48 months<br/>60 months</td>      
                        <td class="blue_2">$476.93<br/>$373.20<br/>$311.30</td>
                        <td rowspan="3" border-collapse="collapse" class="blue_3"></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr class="big_box">
                        <td style="background-color:#C7DDF3;">$25,000</td>
                        <td class="blue_1">6 months<br/>48 months<br/>60 months</td>      
                        <td class="blue_2">$794.88.93<br/>$622.01<br/>$518.84</td>
                        <td rowspan="3" border-collapse="collapse" class="blue_3"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post this in the question. This is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
table td{
     border:1px solid #001F5B;

}

table .big_box td{

    padding-top:16px;
    padding-bottom:16px;
    color:#001F5B;

}

table .top_box td{
    padding:10px;
    color:#F6F9FD;

}

table span{
    font-size:.5em;
    position:relative;
    top:-9px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.blue_1{background-color:#C7DDF3;}
.blue_2{background-color:#C7DDF3;}
.blue_3
{background-color:#C7DDF3;
font-size: 15px;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

this is the CSS

Comment: Please edit your question and post this in the question. This is not an answer to the original question.